# Cucumber 4.2 Report Implementation

Tags: java, cucumber, report

I'm had implemented Cucumber 4.2 and i need report for this framework. As i head, cucumber 4.2 uses event based reporting rather than formatter. Can anyone suggest some example code or website for report implement either in extent report or generate from json. Which report is better?

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/features/",
        glue = "com.peterwkc.stepsdef",
        plugin = {"com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:", 
        "json:target/cucumber-report.json"})
public class ParallelRunner {


}


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

**Questions (Edit):** 
I'm using extent report adapter but i cannot find the generated report.

**1**. Where is the generated report located?

Thanks.

Comment: http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/4/java/cucumber4.html or https://github.com/trivago/cluecumber-report-plugin or https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/runtime/formatter/HTMLFormatter.java if u wanna look at event based reporting

Comment: by default the report is generated at - test-output/HtmlReport/ExtentHtml.html. Unless u have changed it in extent.properties using extent.reporter.html.out property

Comment: I don't see any folder called test-output under target. What wrong with it?

Comment: It is not inside target folder. It should be in the same level as the target folder.

Comment: Nope, there is no folder name test-output generated.

Comment: U can add this as system property. If u are using surefire or failsafe add this - <configuration>
    <systemPropertyVariables>
        <extent.reporter.html.start>true</extent.reporter.html.start>
        <extent.reporter.html.out>test-output/HtmlReport/ExtentHtml.html</extent.reporter.html.out>
    </systemPropertyVariables>
</configuration> or can pass it in the maven command - mvn clean install -DargLine="-Dextent.reporter.html.start=true -Dextent.reporter.html.out=test-output/HtmlReport/ExtentHtml.html"

Comment: How to configure the extent report? Using extent.properties???

Comment: extent.properties, place it in the src/test/resources folder

Comment: What are the properties use to set the background to dark theme.

Comment: Check this [link](http://grasshopper.tech/824/) and search for section titled 'Report Settings'.